# difficulty removing skype for business and installing regular skype

Tags: skype

this is very strange.

I used to use Skype.

At some point maybe I needed to uninstall and reinstall it but things went downhill from there.

If I click the bottom left(the orb), I see this

[image]

So I look to uninstall Skype for business('cos I guess it might nag me to pay at some point), and install regular Skype.  I haven't even used "Skype for business"

And I don't know what Skype-8...exe is, if that's Skype business or regular skype.

If I go to "programs and features".

Then I don't see Skype listed

[image]

If I try to go to Skype.com then straight away it redirects me to some russian version of the website

[image]

So how am I meant to uninstall Skype for business, and find the regular Skype?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

***The solution for me was to install Skype from the stand alone installer.***  I have no idea why Microsoft is trying to force Teams on all of us when it won't do the simple 1 on 1 that Skype has always provided.  Teams is cool and all.. but it doesn't replace Skype.

First, uninstall Skype for Business.  See [this for instructions if you need them.](https://thinkmobiles.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-skype-for-business/)  I myself looked in "apps and features" and I looked in the regular uninstaller.  I can't remember which one worked (its been a while).

Now, go to Microsoft and download the stand alone MSI for installing Skype. [I found a copy here (answers.microsoft.com).](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/sk_news/you-can-now-distribute-skype-8-to-your/3c1ca7fe-a4d9-484f-b0c0-f1df50f1877a?tm=1551298923696)

After doing these steps, I had a regular copy of "good ol' skype".

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was, I attempted(intended!) to  reinstall Skype for Business in the hope that if I do so then I could uninstall it.  It wasn't showing in Win7's "Programs and features".

So I went to skype.com , it still redirected to skype.ru I clicked translate and followed the download link and that was skype.  `Skype-8.66.0.74.exe`  If I go to skype.com now it still redirects but google offers no option to translate. But I see the link still, it's

The link under the big blue button

[image]

That link is apparently russian for "or download skype"

(turns out that's the regular Skype)

As for "Skype for business", it's not showing even in uninstallation programs. I have just deleted the shortcuts from the start menu, so it doesn't bother me.

[image]

Skype, the one I just downloaded / showed the link for, basically logged in just prompting me for a password but remembered my username.